# How to parse html form data into a document

Tags: html, forms, document

I would like to be able to take form data and parse the input into a document, made up of a mixture of text and code.  For example:

Form input:

First name: John
Surname: Doe

Output:

There was a man called Mr **Doe**.  His first name is **John**.

What would be the easiest method for doing this.  I've looked around and found examples where the input is displayed, but as yet I've not managed to find a way to get the result that I am trying to achieve.

I have written the form in HTML, with a Submit button at the end.  I've tried writing a javascript function to pull the fields with no success, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was two step process.

1) Extracting the data

2) writing to a word doc

1) Extracting: We can use beautifulsoup(bs4) to extract from html

2) Writing: we can place merge fields in word doc in between the sentences or in a table. When the output comes it will directly populate the text into these fiels. In your example:  There was a man called Mr . His first name is .
So we populate text which extracted into these two fields.

There is a great tutorial here http://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html

Comment: thanks for your quick response - that document looks promising - I will try and follow that for starters.

Comment: I've looked at the above, and it didn't seem to fit well for me.  I have looked at the following javascript option, but whilst it was working, it now seems not to - any advice would be appreciated:                                                                            
 <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function display() {
  DispWin = window.open('','NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=1250,height=975')                                       
  message = "Lots of message here<br /><br />";
  message += "Lots more message here><br />";

Comment: <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function display() {
  DispWin = window.open('','NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=1250,height=975')   
  message = "Lots of message here<br /><br />";
  message += "Lots more message here><br />";         
  message += "Lots of message here<br /><br />";
  message += "Lots more message here><br />";                  
  ...                                                                       
 DispWin.document.write(message);
}
</script>

Comment: I have been able to grab the data from the form using this method, but now it seems to open the window but not write the message (Google Chrome - if it makes any difference).  So that you are aware, I need to be able to output around 10k lines of data.